# Reorder TableView using fetchedResultsController using Swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift4

What I am trying to do is reordering my tableview cell. My tableview has sections: the data model the simple : list of product and each product has a category.

I am using UITableViewDropDelegate,UITableViewDragDelegate because I don't like the editing mode in tableview (the red button drive me crazy):

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {


    var objects = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects! as [TblProduits]
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil

    //get the destination section
    let myDestSection = objects[destinationIndexPath.row]

    let object = objects[sourceIndexPath.row]
    objects.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)

    //updating product categorie with the destination categorie before inserting 
    object.categorie = myDestSection.categorie

    objects.insert(object, at: destinationIndexPath.row)


    fctSaveListDesProduits()
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
  }
```

My app crash on this function when I try to drop a product in another section with this error:

> due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (1 moved in, 0 moved out).'

How can I resolve this?

### Updated

Here is the full code:

```
 @IBOutlet var TblView_Produit: UITableView!

let Mycontext =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate   as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let Myrequest : NSFetchRequest<TblProduits> = TblProduits.fetchRequest()
var fetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController<TblProduits>!
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     TblView_Produit.dragDelegate = self
    TblView_Produit.dropDelegate = self
   TblView_Produit.dragInteractionEnabled = true

    // Load Data
    Fct_loadListDesProduits()
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

}

func Fct_SaveListDesProduits() {
    do {
        try Mycontext.save()
        //    print ("saved ligne \(i)")
    } catch {
        debugPrint ("there is an error  \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

  func Fct_loadListDesProduits () {



    let MySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(TblProduits.categorie.categorie_Name), ascending: true)
    Myrequest.sortDescriptors = [MySortDescriptor]
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: Myrequest, managedObjectContext: Mycontext, sectionNameKeyPath:  #keyPath(TblProduits.categorie.categorie_Name), cacheName: nil)

    do {
        try  fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

    } catch {
        debugPrint ("there is an error  \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }
}


   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let sections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections else {
        return 0
    }

    return sections.count
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let sections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections else {
        return 0
    }

    return sections[section].numberOfObjects
}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    guard let sections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections else {
        return ""
    }

    return sections[section].name
}


// MARK: - FetchedResultsController Delegate

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch(type) {
    case .insert:
        if  let Myindexpath = newIndexPath {

            self.TblView_Produit.insertRows(at: [Myindexpath], with: .left)

        }
        break;

    case .delete:
        if let MyindexPath = indexPath {
            TblView_Produit.deleteRows(at: [MyindexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break;

    case .move:


        break;
    case .update:


        break;
    }



}


func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    TblView_Produit.endUpdates()
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    TblView_Produit.beginUpdates()
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ProduitTableViewCell
    if let ProduitName = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).produit_name { //ProductTable[indexPath.row].produit_name{


        cell.SetListeDesProduits(ProduitName: ProduitName)
    }
    //    cell.isEditing =  self.tableView(tableView, canMoveRowAt: indexPath)
    return cell
}


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {


var objects = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects! as [TblProduits]
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil

//get the destination section
let myDestSection = objects[destinationIndexPath.section]

let object = objects[sourceIndexPath.row]
objects.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)

//updating product categorie with the destination categorie before inserting 
object.categorie = myDestSection.categorie

objects.insert(object, at: destinationIndexPath.row)


fctSaveListDesProduits()
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
  }
```

### Update

Logging numberOfrowinsection:

I have only three sections and each section has only one item

```
section :  2
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  0
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  1
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  2
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  0
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  1
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  2
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  0
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  1
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  2
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  0
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  1
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
```

When I do the drag drop from the item from the second section to the first

```
section 
section :  0
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  1
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1
section :  2
sections[section].numberOfObjects: 1

018-01-26 19:56:05.492956+0100 ShopTogether[8815:1168659] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/UITableView.m:2011
2018-01-26 19:56:05.513608+0100 ShopTogether[8815:1168659] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (1 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

**// Update Fetchcontroller**

I think that the problem is when I display the sections

In fact when I put nil in sectionNameKeyPath: nil ==> my table view has no sections any more and I have no crash any more **but I want sections in my table view**.

```
 fetchedResultsController = 
   NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: Myrequest, managedObjectContext: Mycontext,
   sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

I am still searching for an answer, but I hope that drag and drop between different **sections is allowed in tableview**.

Comment: Are you sure it's `let MyDestSection = objects[destinationIndexPath.row]` rather than `let MyDestSection = objects[destinationIndexPath.section]`? And please conform to the naming convention that variable and function names start with a lowercase letter and is *camelCased*, not *snake_cased*

Comment: @vadian : I update the code conform to the naming convention. and I tried your suggestion and still have the same error.

Comment: Does changing `objects[destinationIndexPath.row]` to `objects[destinationIndexPath.section]` solve the issue?

Comment: @vadian no still same error.

Comment: If you move or delete rows, your object model needs to agree with the table changes you made. i.e., the results from 'numberOfRowsInSection' delegate. I don't see how you are separating your objects into sections, Look in 'numberOfRowsInSection' or 'cellForRowAt:' for your answer.

Comment: @FryAnEgg.   i am using the fetchefResultsControlller.sections to split sections :  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let sections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections else {
            return 0
        }
        
        return sections[section].numberOfObjects
    }

Comment: @FryAnEgg . I posted the full code.

Comment: If the objects are split into sections why are you using destinationIndexPath.row to set myDestSection? Log the output from numberOfRowsInSection. It looks like your objects is just an array instead of an array of arrays.

Comment: @FryAnEgg thank you for replying but i didn’t understand how i should resolve the issue

Comment: @FryAnEgg I just update the code with the logging parts. thanks for helping  in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am not sure this will be the cleanest way** but I solved my problem by regenerating the TableView and inserting object after updating the category.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil
    var objects = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
    let objectSource = fetchedResultsController.object(at: IndexPath(row: sourceIndexPath.row, section: sourceIndexPath.section))
    let MyCategorie = fetchedResultsController.object(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: destinationIndexPath.section)).categorie
    objectSource.categorie = MyCategorie
    objects?.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    objects?.insert(objectSource, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    Fct_SaveListDesProduits()
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    // REGENRATING TABLEVIEW 
    Fct_loadListDesProduits()
 }
```